# How do I nest routes with React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have multiple layouts that should include different screens. Each layout has its own header, footer, and other things similar pages should share. Here is the code I came up with:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path={['/index', '/about']} component={BaseLayout}>
    <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </Route>
  <Route path={['/sign-in', '/sign-up']} component={AuthLayout}>
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
  </Route>
  <Route path={['/stats'} component={DashboardLayout}>
    <Route path="/stats" component={Stats} />
  </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The code above obviously won't work because:

> Warning: You should not use `<Route component>` and  in
>   the same route; `<Route component>` will be ignored

Answers to similar questions on SO suggest to use wrapper components directly:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <BaseLayout>
    <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </BaseLayout>
  <AuthLayout>
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
  </AuthLayout>
  <DashboardLayout>
    <Route path="/stats" component={Stats} />
  </DashboardLayout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Problem with this approach is that even that it renders a single screen, it also renders elements from the other layouts, i.e. if you're on the index page rendered inside the `BaseLayout`, you will see elements from the `AuthLayout` and `DashboardLayout` too. Which kinda makes sense because they are not wrapped in a `Route`.

Some people suggested to grab the content of all layouts and add them as siblings to the current Routes. However this is a mess to me. I do want to keep all layouts in separate files and only pass screens as children to them.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It seems you are just trying to group routes by some relationtionship in code. Have you tried using `exact` on some of the routes so you don't get multiple matches?

Comment: Actually, I see what you are going for here. I may suggest converting your layout components into HOCs that handle the layout, and take your route "component" as a parameter and return that component within the correct layout wrapper, i.e. `<Route path="/index" component={BaseLayout(Index)} />`

Comment: @DrewReese, the main idea was to prevent rerendering of shared elements (e.g. header, footer) of screens wrapped in the same layout when I go from one page to another. With HOCs they will be rerendered anyway, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but each route gets rendered independently of others.  If you have different headers/footers and that is all that is different, then you can also just render those directly as well on their own routes, as multiple routes and render multiple components. The app I'm building for my company has a header component and footer component that have routers internally to return different components when on different routes, separate from what matches in the router in the content area.

Comment: @DrewReese, each layout has its unique grid, elements, etc. I cannot really use routes for each grid element inside a layout. So I only want to pass those screens as child elements and only update them when I go from one page to another.

Comment: Yeah, the HOC pattern can do that, or wrap the component explicitly as @Prakash has done in their provided solution below.

Comment: @DrewReese, say you're on the `/index` page. If you go to `/about` it will rerender all of your HOC (including the screen itself and layout elements), i.e. everything that's in the Route's component prop. I don't want that. I ony want to rerender the screen component. Layout specific elements will be the same, so I don't want to rerender them.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow, the re-rendering on a new route is going to happen anyway. 
 It sounds like your code needs a refactoring and some decoupling if there are pieces common to multiple routes you don't want re-rendered.  Factor out the pieces that are common (i.e. independent of route and content), keep the parts that directly affect the routed component.

Comment: @DrewReese, I may be dumb, but I think I did exactly that by moving common pieces to layout and moving them out of routes. The problem is that I have multiple layouts which is what the question is about.

Comment: I get your ask, but clearly, as you've stated, when switching routes (from index to about) that there is something in common getting rerendered. *That* is the piece that needs further refactoring. The layout container needs to wrap the route's component as it has grid elements, but the header and footer you mention can both likely be pulled from the layout containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rough draft of a potential layout structure:

```
<Header>
  <Route>
    <Route path={['/index', '/about']} component={HeaderComponent} />
    <Route path={['/sign-in', '/sign-up']} component={AuthHeaderComponent} />
  </Route>
</Header>
<Screens>
  <Route>
    <Route path="/index" component={BaseLayout(Index)} />
    <Route path="/about" component={BaseLayout(About)} />
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={AuthLayout(SignIn)} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={AuthLayout(SignUp)} />
    <Route path="/stats" component={DashboardLayout(Stats)} />
  </Route>
</Screens>
<Footer>
  <FooterComponent />
</Footer>
```

In this example the wrappers are HOCs so they can handle passing all props from the route down to the page component, but if you just wanted to do an inline wrapper you could use the [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) function:

```
<Route
  path="/index"
  render={routeProps => {
    return (
      <BaseLayout>
        <Index {...routeProps}/>
      </BaseLayout>
    );
  }}
/>
```

[edit] A sample Layout HOC ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html))

```
const withBaseLayout = WrappedComponent => {
  // any business logic required for the layout
  // layoutProps, style, etc...
  return (
    <BaseLayout {...layoutProps}>
      <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> // these are all the passed in props
      // you can inject more props into Wrapped component as well
      // i.e. redux's connect or react-router-dom's withRouter HOCs
    </BaseLayout>
  );
}

// in index.js
export default withBaseLayout(Index);

// in route
<Route path="/index" component={Index} /> // already wrapped
```

Or directly as Component

```
const BaseLayoutHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  // any business logic required for the layout
  // layoutProps, style, etc...
  return (
    <BaseLayout {...layoutProps}>
      <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    </BaseLayout>
  );
}

// in route
<Route path="/index" component={BaseLayoutHOC(Index)} />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an aswer. Do you mind to share what a `BaseLayout(Index)` HOC might look like?

Comment: @sdvnksv added some simple HOC and usage example.